# How to change color of Image at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I would like to know is there any way by which we can change the Image color at runtime.
for e.g lets say I am having a JPG bind to an Image control of ASP.Net. Next I am having a dropdown List which gives me the various color option like red,gree,etc. I would now like to change the color of the Image to the one selected in the droprdown List.

Comment: You'll need to say more about what you're doing. "The image" doesn't mean anything to anyone else.

Comment: Do you have a picture you want to manipulate, or is it because you need illustrate the selected color?

What im trying to figure out is, if you want to make a picture of, lets say a dog, more greener when green is selected. Or you want to just show a picture of a green color.

Comment: It sounds to me like the OP wants to change the color of an "image"  client-side. Could you better define what "image" means in this context? Do you mean the JPG, a border/background to the JPG?

Answer (score 12):

Here is a code sample that loads a JPEG, changes any red pixels in the image to blue, and then displays the bitmap in a picture box:

```
Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile("image.jpg");
for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
    {
        if (bmp.GetPixel(x, y) == Color.Red)
        {
            bmp.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Blue);
        }
    }
}
pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
```

Warning:  GetPixel and SetPixel are incredibly slow.  If your images are large and/or performance is an issue, there is a much faster way to read and write pixels in .NET, but it's a little bit more work.

Comment: Comparing the GetPixel result with a Color doesn't always work. You should compare their ToArbg() results as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7464994/how-to-compare-a-color-by-the-getpixel-method-and-a-color-passed-in-a-method-lik

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure my code would *ever* work. I think even if the bitmap's pixel color has the exact same ARGB values as Color.Red, it still will not be equivalent to Color.Red.

Answer (score 0):

You also try this for web (asp.net) , you can ignore the logic but can see what getpixel & setpixel doing

```
 public string FileUpload( HttpPostedFileBase file )
  {
     Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(file.InputStream);
     string valid = "";

     for(int i = 0; i < bmp.Width; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < bmp.Height; j++) {
           if(bmp.GetPixel(i , j).B < 20) {
              if(bmp.GetPixel(i , j).B == bmp.GetPixel(i , j).G &&
                 bmp.GetPixel(i , j).B == bmp.GetPixel(i , j).R) {
                 valid = valid + bmp.GetPixel(i , j). + "<br/>";
                 bmp.SetPixel(i , j , Color.DarkGreen);
              }
           }
        }
     }

     SaveImage(bmp);

     return valid;
  }

  private void SaveImage( Bitmap newbmp )
  {
     string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images") , "ScaledImage.jpeg");
     newbmp.Save(path , System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

I am also facing trouble to under this question. after that based on the some information. I wrote the code manually.Now it works well. If you want to check.you can use it.

code for change the background image during runtime in C#.net

you can use simply this code. That is, ==>

```
string str; 
OpenFileDialog od = new OpenFileDialog(); 
if (od.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
{ 
    str = od.FileName;
    this.BackgroundImage=Image.FromFile(str); 
}
```