# How to compare a Color by the GetPixel Method and a Color passed in a method like Color.Black?

Tags: c#, image, colors, getpixel

I have a loop that gets pixelcolors from an image and try to see if they are the same as the Color I passed into the method as parameter.

I tried the `Equals` method but it doesn't work. I also tried the `ToKnown` method.
It looks like that match doesn't work beacuse the values that synthesize the two colors don't match.

Example:

With GetPixel:

```
{Name=ff000000, ARGB=(255, 0, 0, 0)}
```

Color.Black:

```
{Name=Black, ARGB=(255, 0, 0, 0)}
if (pixelColor.ToArgb().Equals(startingOffsetColor.ToArgb())) { }
```

The code above works, but I still want to know if there is any better method or any method that can reduce any CPU overhead, because I'm using this inside a loop statement.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.op_equality.aspx), the Color.Equality Operator...

> ...compares more than the ARGB values of the Color structures. It also does a comparison of some state flags. If you want to compare just the ARGB values of two Color structures, compare them using the ToArgb method

So the method that you are using is correct for comparing the raw values

**EDIT**

`.ToArgb()` returns an `int` so you can just use `==` for comparison, you don't need to use `.Equals()` if you find it too verbose.

Comment: Yes it's just an int so I could use just "==".
It's my Java BG that made me use directly Equals without checking return type first.