# Why does this color comparison fail?

Tags: c#, colors

Why does this assertion fail?

```
Assert.AreEqual( Color.Red, Color.FromArgb( Color.Red.A, Color.Red.R, Color.Red.G, Color.Red.B ) );
```

Comment: Do this: Color.Red.ToArgb() == Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0).ToArgb()

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7464994/how-to-compare-a-color-by-the-getpixel-method-and-a-color-passed-in-a-method-lik

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is how Colors comparison implemented:

```csharp
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (obj is Color)
    {
        Color color = (Color) obj;
        if ((this.value == color.value)
            && (this.state == color.state)
            && (this.knownColor == color.knownColor))
        {
            return ((this.name == color.name)
                || ((this.name != null)
                   && (color.name != null)
                   && this.name.Equals(color.name)));
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

How it works:

1. Field `value` compared. It is Argb values of current instance (they are stored in one field of type `long`). So, if Argb different, we have different colors. You pass this step successfully.
2. Field `state` compared. It shows the way how color was created: from Argb, from KnownColor, or by name. **Actually your comparison fails on this step.**
3. Field `knownColor` compared. It has value of KnownColor enum, or zero, if color was not created from known color.
4. Field `name` compared. It has `null` value for all colors except ones created by name.

So, if you want to compare values of colors, you should use `value` field in comparison (it is returned by ToArgb method):

```csharp
Assert.AreEqual(color1.ToArgb(), color2.ToArgb());
```

**Edit**

To create copy of some color you can use following extension method:

```csharp
public static class ColorHelper
{
    public static Color Copy(this Color color)
    {
        if (color.IsKnownColor)
            return Color.FromKnownColor(color.ToKnownColor());

        if (color.IsNamedColor)
            return Color.FromName(color.Name);

        // this is better, then pass A,r,g,b separately
        return Color.FromArgb(color.ToArgb()); 
    }
```

Now assertion passes:

```csharp
Assert.AreEqual(Color.Red, Color.Red.Copy());
```

But it makes no sense, because you can use single color instance in every place of your program :)

Answer (score 2):

`Color.Red` is a named color, while `Color.FromArgb(...)` is not. So they're not considered equal, even though they have the same ARGB values. Note that the string representation is also different:

```
Color.Red.ToString()           : "Color [Red]"
Color.FromArgb(...).ToString() : "Color [A=255, R=255, G=0, B=0]"
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Equals` override of the `Color` class checks, whether both colors are named (known) colors or not:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (obj is Color)
    {
        Color color = (Color) obj;
        if (((this.value == color.value) && (this.state == color.state)) && (this.knownColor == color.knownColor))
        {
            return ((this.name == color.name) || (((this.name != null) && (color.name != null)) && this.name.Equals(this.name)));
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since Color is a struct, it has many properties other than just ARGB values. For instance, if you create a color using two different approaches, they will have different names; thus they will not be equal.

```
        Color a = Color.Red;            
        Color b = Color.FromArgb(a.A, a.R, a.G, a.B);

        string name1 = a.Name; //name is Red
        string name2 = b.Name; //name is ffff0000
```

Structs do not have any equality logic by themselves(i.e. if you want to use '==').Thus for every struct, this operator shall be defined. If you investigate Color, you will see the following definition of '==' operator. It depends on how this operator is implemented.

```
    // Summary:
    //     Tests whether two specified System.Drawing.Color structures are equivalent.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   left:
    //     The System.Drawing.Color that is to the left of the equality operator.
    //
    //   right:
    //     The System.Drawing.Color that is to the right of the equality operator.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     true if the two System.Drawing.Color structures are equal; otherwise, false.
    public static bool operator ==(Color left, Color right);
```

Also 'Equals' is overriden in the struct such that it checks for equivalence of structs;

```
    // Summary:
    //     Tests whether the specified object is a System.Drawing.Color structure and
    //     is equivalent to this System.Drawing.Color structure.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   obj:
    //     The object to test.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     true if obj is a System.Drawing.Color structure equivalent to this System.Drawing.Color
    //     structure; otherwise, false.
    public override bool Equals(object obj);
```

Comment: Not true. In case of `Color b = Color.FromArgb(a.A, a.R, a.G, a.B);` name will be `null`.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky have you tried this? I have tried and it behaves how it is stated in the answer.

Comment: Property `Name` just generates string if there is none actually. I pointed to this, because property `Name` is not used in comparison. Only actual field `name` is used.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky I do not know about the how equals or '==' operator is implemented but I want to give a general idea about how equivalence of two structs are handled. How can I view the source code where this is implemented?

Comment: there are great tools like Reflector, or JustDecompile by Telerik :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a consequence of the way the `System.Drawing.Color` structure is implemented. It has a separate `Name` property, which is "Red" for `Color.Red` but is different when you create your own `Color` from `Color.Red`. `System.Windows.Media.Color` (ie. WPF's `Color` implementation) does not exhibit this same problem.