# c# printing black and whites out of image

Tags: c#, console

I need a code that reads a 160x160 image of a maze, checks if it has white or black pixels and prints the pixel x and y position with information if it is black or white

Example:

134, 27: w

I need it for every single pixel

Right Now I have the following:

```
Bitmap maze = new Bitmap ("images/maze.png");
int[][] colors = new int[maze.Width][];
for (int i = 0; i < colors.Length; i++) 
    colors[i] = new int[maze.Height];
for (int x = 0; x < maze.Width; x++) 
    for (int y = 0; y < maze.Height; y++) 
        colors[x][y] = maze.GetPixel (x, y);
```

Comment: That code doesn't compile. GetPixel returns a Color structure and you cannot convert it to an integer

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: it isn't homework, I need it for a big project, if it was homework I wouldn't read about 1000 mazes

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't store a `Color` as an `int`, which is why you should switch from `int[][]` to `Color[][]`.

To output your desired result, simply loop over the array again, formatting the result a bit using `string.Format()` and some conditional operators.

```
for (int x = 0; x < maze.Width; x++) 
    for (int y = 0; y < maze.Height; y++) 
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}, {1}: {2}",
            x, y,
            colors[x][y].ToArgb() == Color.Black.ToArgb() ? "b" : (colors[x][y].ToArgb() == Color.White.ToArgb() ? "w" : "n")
            ));
```

Note that this code outputs `n` if the pixel is neither black nor white.

Also note that you can omit the `string.Format()` method aswell, since the `Console.WriteLine()` function contains an overload with formatting possibility.

Edit:

If you want to define a color as *white* if their RGB color is greater than, for example 170, you could add up their RGB values (excluding alpha values here, since reading image data is mostly done without transparency) and check if their sum is greater than 170 * 3.

```
Color current = colors[x][y];
int rgbSum = current.R + current.G + current.B;
char whiteOrBlack = (170 * 3 < rgbSum) ? 'w' : 'b';
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}, {1}: {2}", x, y, whiteOrBlack));
```

I just want to point out that *170* is a rather odd number to use here. Maybe it's more likely that you meant 128 (i.e. half a byte)?

Comment: The read colors won't be comparable to the built-in known colors in that way. The comparison should be done with `colors[x][y].ToArgb() == Color.Black.ToArgb()`. Since `ToArgb()` returns an int, there's no need to change the structure of the `colors` array, so long as you're assigning the pixel to it through the `ToArgb()` method.

Comment: @JonathonChase You can't? Doesn't the `Color` class has a `==` operator that compares the encoded color values of the two parameters? I switched it to include `.ToArgb()` anyways, as you said.

Comment: While it does, the equality operator also compares some state flags that would not get picked up reading the colors from the `GetPixel` call. You can read more about that [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7464994/how-to-compare-a-color-by-the-getpixel-method-and-a-color-passed-in-a-method-lik) and [this MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.op_equality.aspx)

Comment: @JonathonChase I just looked it up quickly in the source code myself, it really does additionally compare states and other stuff together with the value comparison, you were absolutely right.

Comment: I'm having about 13 errors

Colors doesn't exist
Bool To Char

Errors caused by errors

Current doesn't exist

Comment: @Sport Mind sharing these errors by editing them into your question?

Comment: @IanH. His issue with Colors doesn't exist is that you're using `Colors` instead of `Color` in your first code block.

Comment: @JonathonChase Ugh, I am used to Unity's color structures, thanks for pointing out my error, fixed it.

Comment: Colors still doesn't exist...

Help

Comment: @Sport You need to add a reference to `System.Drawing` to access the `System.Drawing.Color` type. The `Colors` was just a spelling error by me.

Comment: I can access System.Drawing but I can't access System.Drawing.Color, I've added the reference, helps?

Comment: I've changed Using to Using Static, Right now the color is:
Embedded statement cannot be a declaration or a labeled statement

Comment: @Sport If your for-loop does not contain a single line of code you need to add the curly brackets `{}` around the loop code block.

Comment: Alright, Half of the errors gone,
Name color does not exist
Can't convert from bool to char in assigning blackorwhite
rgbsum can't be compared

Comment: @Sport I forgot to add the parenthesis around the operation, check the edited line with `char blackOrWhite`.

Comment: Making that, makes the line below say that WhiteOrBlack doesn't exist, c# is bugged

Comment: Thanks, I've only got an error left:The name 'color' doesn't exist in the current context

Comment: @Sport Then you included the reference to the `System.Drawing.Color` incorrectly.

Comment: I'm having trouble as I've added it correctly, Error:The type or namespace 'colors' does not exist in the namespace 'system.Drawing' (are you missing an assembly refference?)

Comment: @Sport Have you added a reference to the DLL of System.Drawing?

Comment: Doesn't let me do it, outputs an error and asks to use the .net

Comment: @Sport How did you add the reference and where did you locate the DLL?

Comment: Take this to discord, I don't want to make an extensive reply log
Illusion... Maybe?#2824