# WPF Image, changing color of pixels

Tags: wpf, image, repaint, pixel

I have a problem. I need to fill (or repaint) some pixels at image, stored in Image control. This is a png image. I mean, that all black pixels should be filled with, for example, red color. How can I do this? I thought I can access directly to pixels and using XOR change special bits, but I don't know how to do this. Or maybe there is an easier way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `GetPixel` and `SetPixel` methods should work for what you need.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383103/how-to-change-color-of-image-at-runtime-c-sharp-asp-net/383305#383305) has a code sample that you should be able to adopt for your use.

Comment: Thank you, It works. I'm using WPF, but I've understood, what to do - just create BitmapSource from Bitmap, using Interop