# asp.net How to get the id of the button user clicked

Tags: asp.net

I have a small problem. I am developing an online seat reservation system which allow users to click and select seats. I am using buttons for seats. I am writing a method for the button click event for all buttons. I need to know how to identify the id of the button, user clicked. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

When you use a *button clicked* event, the signature of the method that'll handle the event goes like this:

```
protected void foo (object sender, EventArgs e)
```

`sender` in this case is the button that was clicked. Just cast it to Button again and there you have it. Like this:

```
Button button = (Button)sender;
string buttonId = button.ID;
```

You can have all your buttons pointing their `Click` event to the same method like this.

Comment: @jabu.hlong I saw your edit. It is correct, I don't know why it was rejected. I am correcting my answer here, thank you.

Answer (score 6):

The first parameter of your event handler (`object source` or sometimes `object sender`) is a reference to the button that was clicked. All you need to do is cast it and then you can retrieve the id value, e.g.:

```
void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = sender as Button;
    if (button != null)
    {
       //get the id here
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 because it is correct, but I simply had to say this: if you're getting a null reference for the sender in a method called by a `Button.Click` event handler, someone is doing something very sick somewhere.

Comment: Regardless of circumstance it is always best practice to check for null after a safe cast.

Comment: but there is no such keyword "sender"... Sorry I did not understand the code

Comment: @LIH you use that piece of code inside the method that handles the `Click` event.

Comment: @LIH I've just updated my code example to make it more obvious that it's the body of an event handler.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's another way to do this method you may not thought of it, 
why don't you put an

> Image control

you only need switch the image's color for this method, the first one we assume that it's **Red** and it means **free** seat, and the second one is **Blue** and means **taken** .

here is a link you may need to know about this issue [How to change color of Image at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383103/how-to-change-color-of-image-at-runtime-c-sharp-asp-net)

Hope I could gave you a better idea. thank you

Comment: Not the answer the OP or anyone else was thinking about, but +1 for the idea. This is way better in terms of user friendliness and usability.

Comment: BTW he would still need to know how to fetch data from the button even if he did it this way.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but hopefully it helps **someone** out there having the same trouble I was here in 2019! This is my solution using the Tag property of the button with Binding through XAML. Worked great for me, even though it might be a little hacky:

In your button click event:

```cs
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Button EditButton = (Button)e.Source;
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(EditButton.Tag);

            //do your stuff
        }
```

In your XAML:

```
<Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Edit" Tag="{Binding whateverInt}" />
```